# Backup failed Another duplcity instance is already running with this archive directory in 22.04

Tags: backup, deja-dup, duplicity

I am using Ubunbut 22.04 with automatic backups scheduled through Déjà Dup. The PC is backed up to an external USB hard drive and I only plug in that hard drive when I see the Duplicity backup notification.

Usually the backup proceeded as expected. But sometimes I see this error:

[image: Backup failed: Another duplicity instance is already running with this archive directory]

Rebooting the PC usually fixes the problem, but that is very inconvenient. Another option is to kill the Déjà Dup and Duplicity processes and then manually run the backup, but that doesn't seem like a good/safe practice.

Are there options to either avoid this problem or to let the automatic backups proceed smoothly with minimal manual intervention?